# how to restore a locally deleted repository with github client

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, github-for-windows

So I was using a BitBucket repository with the GitHub client, the repository I have in BitBucket is the main and older one which misses important and hard-worked files saved on my computer. I wanted to switch from BitBucket to GitHub so I went to the repository settings and changed the primary remote URL from the BitBucket one to the new GitHub repository which is new and empty, then I clicked commit and clicked synced and then I got a 'failed to commit' error and instantly saw that all of my files on my locally saved repository have been deleted.

Is it possible to get them back? If it is then how?

Comment: Have you tried running `git revert` on the repo that was affected? It should reverse the pushed commit and make a new commit with the files that you lost.

Comment: I just tried it now, how could I revert the commit if the commit never took place?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if the commit never took place then you won't be able to reverse it... Are you saying that you manually _accidentally_ deleted files and you're trying to recover them? Because that won't work unless you delete them via git, git only indexes changes that it sees and if it you force deleted files; git can't do anything about them.

Comment: When I tried to commit right before the files were deleted GitHub client popped up with a 'failed to commit' error. The commit doesn't show up on either BitBucket or GitHub.

Comment: Could you please post the `git log` output so we can see what's actually happened.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T72KQH1V Here it is.

Comment: And please also add the output of `git status` and `git stash list`. If there is anything in the latter, try `git stash pop` to resurrect the stash.

Comment: `git status` returns http://pastebin.com/JNtxZYAT

Comment: git stash list is empty